# count distintc date and employee_id

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I have table like this:

| date_entry | emp_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-01 | emp-001 |
| 2024-02-01 | emp-001 |
| 2024-02-01 | emp-002 |
| 2024-02-01 | emp-003 |
| 2024-02-02 | emp-001 |
| 2024-02-02 | emp-002 |
| 2024-02-02 | emp-003 |
| 2024-02-03 | emp-001 |
| 2024-02-03 | emp-002 |
| 2024-02-03 | emp-002 |
| 2024-02-03 | emp-003 |
| 2024-02-04 | emp-002 |
| 2024-02-04 | emp-003 |

I need to count the total of the day employee attend and remove the duplicate entry from date range like this:

date range 2024-02-01 until 2024-02-04:

| emp_id | day_attend |
| --- | --- |
| emp-001 | 3 |
| emp-002 | 4 |
| emp-003 | 4 |

how to query in mysql? please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and straightforward.

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT date_entry) AS day_attend
FROM 
    YourTableName
WHERE 
    date_entry BETWEEN '2024-02-01' AND '2024-02-04'
GROUP BY 
    emp_id
ORDER BY 
    emp_id;
```

Comment: Hi, your solutions works like I expected. thank you!